# Vim `gq` rewrap doesn't work within `:<range> norm` command

Tags: vimscript

I have the following snippet of text and I want the "blah" lines to not wrap.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item
      Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah Blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    \item
      Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah Blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{itemize}
```

I issue `:set tw=9999`, then the following:

```
:g/\<item$/+1 norm gq/\<item/-1
:% g/\<item$/+1 norm gq/\<item/-1
```

Neither seem to do anything, but simply putting the cursor on the first "blah" line and issuing `gq/\<item/-1` works fine:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item
      Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    \item
      Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah Blah
      blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{itemize}
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong.  Can anyone point out my error?

Comment: If you'd finish a command with ^M normally, then you still need that in the `:norm`.

Comment: And there's `J` for joining lines. Maybe that would be more useful to you here.

Comment: Thanks, antony, on both answers. If you want to formally post these as the answer, I'll gladly accept them.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to antony for point out that the problem is solved by adding a `^M` to the comand:

```
:g/\<item$/+1 norm gq/\<item/-1^M
```

I get the ^M by first pressing `ctrl-V`, then either `ctrl-M` or the `Carriage Return` key.

Antony also pointed out the `gq` command can be replaced by the `J` command (for Join).  That works for this example.  In a more complex situation, where a body of text might have under-length and over-length lines due to extensive revision, `gq` is needed. It formats the entire "paragraph".